# sql: delete date passed with GATEDATE()

Tags: mysql

I want to delete the column where date is passed

```
DELETE FROM voyages WHERE date < GETDATE()
```

but it doesn't work, in B.D the date is in this form `yyyy/mm/dd`

Comment: try delete from voyages where date < sysdate

Comment: your sql is not complete, can you edit and post complete sql string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below:

There is no function like `GETDATE()` in mysql.

```
DELETE FROM voyages WHERE date < date_format(curdate(),"%Y/%m/%d")
```

If you mean by date passed is current date then use `curdate()`, else put your date in place of `curdate()`

Comment: :( , error
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '%' in C:\wamp\www\deleteauto.php on line 7

line7 : mysql_query("DELETE FROM voyages WHERE date < date_format(curdate(),"%Y/%m/%d")");

Comment: this is error not in query . quote query properly in function.

Comment: Try this : mysql_query("DELETE FROM voyages WHERE date < date_format(curdate(),'%Y/%m/%d')");

Comment: thxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx :) :) , it is OK :) :) thxxxx again
ca i delete the couloun where date and time passed??

Comment: what you mean by "delete the couloun" ? you said now you able to delete.

Comment: colon , i means :
"DELETE FROM voyages WHERE date < date_format(curdate(),'%Y/%m/%d') && time<time_format(curtime(),'%H/%m'"

it's possible??

Comment: :)  keep it up. Use vote cast for me when you get permission.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a column in a table:

```
ALTER TABLE voyages
DROP COLUMN date_column
```

Although, some databases might not allow deleting important columns..most of them do